# Is firmware machine code?

Tags: assembly, fpga

In terms of the program layers that make up cpus.

c > assembly > machine code > microcode > circuits

Where does firmware fall? Is it the machine code? Do all programs need to be compiled down into machine code, or can it stop at assembly?

Comment: *"or can it stop at assembly"* - assembly language is still just a language, much like C is a language - it still needs to be compiled to machine executable statements. With assembly though it is more low level and less able to be retargeted to different processors unlike higher level languages like C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In terms of the program layers that make up cpus.

There's some confusion in your terminology. A CPU ("Central Processing Unit") is a processor, a complex circuit that is fed values that represent machine instructions and performs resulting operations that modify registers and memory; it is not made up of programming layers.

> c > assembly > machine code > microcode > circuits

This is not an accurate/valid hierarchy. Programs written in C are translated into a lower form by a compiler; that lower form can be assembly language, but it also can be direct binary machine code, or it can be code for a virtual machine layer, such as Java's JVM. Assembly languages are close representations of machine code where instructions, registers, and memory locations are given symbolic names; they are translated by an assembler to binary code but the process is much simpler and more direct than for a compiler. Microcode is a low-level form of machine code. Machine code is not generally translated to microcode, but rather the interpreter of machine code -- the CPU -- may itself be a program written/implemented in microcode that is executed by a low-level microcode processor. Circuits are the underlying hardware stratum that perform the microcode (or machine code if there is no microcode level) operations.

> Where does firmware fall? Is it the machine code?

Firmware is machine code/microcode in a fixed ("firm") form, residing on a ROM or EPROM or even implemented directly in circuits. It is a form of software but is distinguished in that it does not reside in (readily) modifiable memory. It is distinguished from hardware conceptually, as hardware is  circuits, memory, buses, etc. that do not represent a program.

> Do all programs need to be compiled
>   down into machine code, or can it stop
>   at assembly?

As noted above, assembly language is a symbolic representation of machine language; it cannot be directly processed by a CPU; it must be translated into machine language.

More details about all these terms and issues can of course be found in Wikipedia and other internet sources, as well as introductory programming books.

Comment: I like this answer, very detailed.

Answer (score 5):

Firmware is machine code that is typically placed inside some storage on a piece of hardware, to make that hardware function. That is to say, firmware is typically written in a low level language (be it C or assembly), compiled and assembled into machine code, and placed in a known position on this storage, where the hardware, during its startup process can read from a known location, and begin executing that machine code.

Comment: I like this answer, its to the point, but I prefer more detail (sorry)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you call "firmware". If you refer to the software of an embedded system, then it's a program (written in C for example), which is compiled into machine code. In some situations, "firmware" may also refer to microcode.

You can't stop at assembly level: a machine (real or virtual) needs machine code.

However, not all programs are compiled: there are [interpreters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) that execute source code directly.

Answer (score -1):

Firmware w/r to a CPU is the micro code.

Machine code is what the assembly models.

Comment: They don't? Can you give a specific example that I can research?

Comment: 6502, ARM, PIC, AVR to name a few. Most RISC architectures are implemented without microcode. Most CISC use microde. Don't ask me about VLIW :)